# Search Product in Shopify Storefront API

Tags: next.js, shopify, shopify-storefront-api

I am Building an eCommerce App with Nextjs and Shopify Storefront API, I can't find any kind of query to filter all the products in the Shopify Database, this functionality will be used in Searchbar to find the product relevant to the entered text.

How to search for products in the search bar?

Storefront API Version: 2022-01 (Latest)

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented [here](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2022-01/queries/products) it's possible to search through all Shopify products  with the option of using one or more query filter(s), such as "title" for example.

Hope that helps.